# Como criar restrição de acesso para uma ação no yii2.0

Tags: php, yii

Eu preciso que o usuário cliente apenas visualize os registros de posts do meu sistema. Gostaria de saber como restringir as ações na tela para o usuário cliente, para que este usuário possa apenas visualizar os registros, e não apareça para ele os botões de alterar, deletar e cadastrar. O usuário admin que vai possuir o acesso completo ao sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 possui suporte para Controle de Acesso. São eles:

- [Access Control Filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html)
- [RBAC (Role Based Access Control)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html)

Eles são melhor explicados na [documentação](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html). Mas, resumindo:

`AccessControl`, você vai usar num projeto que:

- não possui muitos controllers/actions;
- não haverão muitas alterações de permissões para usuários e as roles* estão bem definidas;
- não serão criadas/editadas com muita frequência.

Isso porque você terá que, em cada controller, definir quais actions cada role* pode realizar.

Já a classe DbManager (que utiliza do conceito [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)), cria as tabelas onde será armazenada toda essa informação de que permissão ou role* cada usuário tem.

Caso essa idéia de ir em cada controler e realizar as alterações não seja viável para seu projeto, eu recomendaria dar uma olhada [nessa biblioteca](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin).

*: nome dado ao papel/profissão/cargo que você atribui aos usuários, ex: *administrador, editor, etc*

Comment: Interessante estou estudando mais sobre RBAC, obrigado!